# fill missing data in pandas time series with data from the previous week(day) or day?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a series of data in a pandas dataframe which I import from a CSV, but this file (sampled per minute) has missing data for entire days. I would like to replace them with the same data of the previous DAY or DAY OF WEEK (7 days before), or, also, with the average values per minute o the previous DAYS or DAYS OF THE WEEK (7 x n days before).

This should be done with pandas or python but I frankly don't know how to do it, maybe try to resample or groupby and then resample again with minute frequency? I don't want all the data to be changed though..

The file looks like this one:

```
...
------------------------
*previous complete data*
------------------------
2018-01-05 00:00:00,2900.41
2018-01-05 00:01:00,2919.24
2018-01-05 00:02:00,2938.07
..
2018-01-05 23:59:00,2994.57
-------------------
*missing days data*
-------------------
2018-01-08 00:00:00,3118.00
2018-01-08 00:01:00,3118.00
2018-01-08 00:02:00,3125.54
...
-------------------------------
*complete data till end of year*
-------------------------------
```

and in the output I would like to obtain the full complete dataset, replacing the missing values with the same WEEKDAY (or DAY BEFORE) values, or the averages. So in case I replace the value with the values of the day before the dataset will look like:

```
...
------------------------
*previous complete data*
------------------------
2018-01-05 00:00:00,2900.41
2018-01-05 00:01:00,2919.24
2018-01-05 00:02:00,2938.07
...
2018-01-05 23:59:00,2994.57
2018-01-**06** 00:00:00,2900.41
2018-01-**06** 00:01:00,2919.24
2018-01-**06** 00:02:00,2938.07
...
2018-01-**06** 23:59:00,2994.57

......

2018-01-08 00:00:00,3118.00
2018-01-08 00:01:00,3118.00
2018-01-08 00:02:00,3125.54
...
-------------------------------
*complete data till end of year*
-------------------------------
```

Thanks to whoever can help.

Comment: Please share sample input clearly and along with sample output. Also, what do you mean by "I would like to replace them with the same data of the previous DAY or DAY OF WEEK (7 days before), or, also, with the average values per minute o the previous DAYS or DAYS OF THE WEEK (7 x n days before)." Are you willing to apply these condition randomly?

Comment: Thanks, I reedited, I just want to avoid interpolation and use either average daily values, or values from previous day or (BETTER) values from the previous WEEKDAY i.e. 7 days before.

Comment: You can try group by minute and .ffill()

Comment: doesn't that simply copy the last valid value for the missing values?

Comment: If you group by minute then the last valid value would be the previous days value. Is that not you want?

Comment: yes this kinda woks thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the code for filling missing datetime with previous day's values.

**Considering sample input**

```
    date        val
0   2018-01-05 00:00:00 2900.41
1   2018-01-05 00:01:00 2919.24
2   2018-01-05 00:02:00 2938.07
3   2018-01-08 00:00:00 3118.00
4   2018-01-08 00:01:00 3118.00
5   2018-01-08 00:02:00 3125.54
```

Now we are trying to fill these values for 2018.01.06 and 2018.01.07 for same timestamp.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df = df.set_index('date')
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range('2018-01-05 00:00:00', 
                         '2018-01-08 00:02:00', freq='1 min')
          ).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'date'})
df = df.groupby(df.date.dt.time).ffill()
```

**Sliced Output for time in input**

```
        date                val
0       2018-01-05 00:00:00 2900.41
1       2018-01-05 00:01:00 2919.24
2       2018-01-05 00:02:00 2938.07
1440    2018-01-06 00:00:00 2900.41
1441    2018-01-06 00:01:00 2919.24
1442    2018-01-06 00:02:00 2938.07
2880    2018-01-07 00:00:00 2900.41
2881    2018-01-07 00:01:00 2919.24
2882    2018-01-07 00:02:00 2938.07
```

**Explanation**

1. We are first converting the 'date' column to Timestamp.
2. Setting the date column as index.
3. We are reindexing the index to fill in missing dates with frequency of 1 min, I have take start date as `'2018-01-05 00:00:00'` and end date as `'2018-01-08 00:02:00'`, please modify it as per you requirement.
4. Since are having all timestamps now, we can reset index to date column.
5. we are grouping now the date column with time part of timestamp and ffill it.

Comment: This also works with Pandas API on Spark